# Gulp can't see scss

Tags: sass, gulp

It's propably some stupid error, but I can't see it!
My gulp can't compile my scss. It seems like I gave him wrong directories, but that was the first thing to check.
There are no errors. Everything seems ok, but it just does not work.
There is this important part of my Gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('styles-dev', function() { 
return gulp.src('src/scss/*.scss')
.pipe(plumber())
.pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
.pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'));
});
```

Folder structure:

```
root < here is gulpfile
  dist
      css
  inc 
  node_modules
  src
      js
      scss
```

Comment: Can you show us your directory structure and where gulp script is located?

Answer (score 0):

I would start from something which works... For example:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles-dev', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'));
});
```

This code adds an error logging, too, so it should be easier to track possible errors...

Then, once you see it working, you can start adding other options and  components (`style`, `plumber`, `autoprefixer`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you have a couple syntax errors:

1. Assuming your `sass` requires [`gulp-sass`](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass), you have an typo: say `outputStyle` instead of `style`
2. Assuming your `autoprefixer` requires [`gulp-autoprefixer`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer), your syntax is wrong (see https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#usage). It should have `{ browsers: [] }`, "last 2 version**s**", and capitalization. I think this will work:

```
.pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'Safari 5', 'IE 8', 'IE 9', 'Opera 12.1'] }))
```

(To be clear, that will support the two most recent versions of all the major browsers PLUS Safari 5, IE 8 & 9, and Opera 12.1. If that isn't what you wanted to support, check out https://github.com/ai/browserslist#queries)

Once you've made those fixes, add error logging to your `plumber`: Replace `.pipe(plumber())` with

```
.pipe(plumber({
  errorHandler: function (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    this.emit('end');
}}))
```

If you still have trouble, let us know what errors are logged in the console and we can help you debug!